# Need to add unknown number of student records to a school record

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, hibernate, struts2

I have a class called school which has a list of students. I need to have a registration page to register a school and all its students. As number of students for each school is unknown, I need to have a 'add student' button in the 'school registration' page to allow users to add all students one by one. I can create a form for registering each school, but am not sure how to implement the 'add students' functionality.

I know it is possible to have a 'add student' button which trigger a lightbox of student registration form, but I do not know how to keep details of each student and then associate them to the school record; because student records need id of school vice versa. Please note I do not want to submit school record and then add the students records, I need to add details of school and all its students at the same time.

```
@Entity
public class School {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String principal;
    private String city;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Student> students;
    ....
}

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @OneToOne
    private School school;
    ....
}
```

**Form**

```
    <s:form method="POST" action="register">
        <s:textfield name="name" label="School's name"/>
        <s:textfield name="principal" label="Principal"/>
        <s:textfield name="city" label="City"/>

    </s:form>
```

Comment: It's usually not necessary nor benefical to express relation-ships from both sides. Actually, the main reason you would have a list of students within school is if there were invariants to be enforced, such as a limited number of added students. Even then, since there might be thousands of students it might be impractical to do so. I would only express the relation from the many-to-one side (Student) and I wouldn't even encapsulate a `School` object, just it's id.

Comment: @plalx dies that mean I should have ManytoOne relationship on school field of the student class? what do you mean by not encapsulating school object?

Comment: I mean that optimally you could also simply hold the School's `id` on the `Student` rather than a `School` object, but holding onto a `School` object can also be fine.

Comment: @plalx I've kept list of students in school  to be easier for me to retrieve students of each school. Imagine I am going to search for students of a school based on its principal name, in that case I need to retrieve id of school first then use that to find all its students, but in this case I can retrieve them all using a single query.

Comment: Students are lazy, among them could be orphans, keeping them in one relationship would be obsolete. You can follow OWL level 1 to establish relations to the object model. Making wrong or unnecessary association leads to improper design and object flow. Trying to implement these feature keep in mind existed patterns like master-detail relationship between tables that you probably map as table per class.

Comment: @RomanC I am a bit confused with your explanation, with the first part of your comment should I remove the @ OneToOne mapping from student class? What do you mean by OWL level 1?

Comment: yes, you should remove it and replace with ManyToOne.

Comment: You should first add school and then you can add students later on...

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm understanding the problem correctly, you have a page to create a school entity and after the school is created, you want it to then proceed to a page to register each student.

Zero is a perfectly valid size for the list of students so you should have no problem creating the school without a single student.  Make sure and save the changes to the DB.

The "add a student" page will need to be passed the ID of the school in order have that information to associate the student to the correct school.  (in the url or as a query string http://example.com/register/student?school=23)  Another way to do that would be to have a dropdown box of possible schools and let them select their school out of the existing schools.

When you create a student you'll assign their school ID appropriately and add the student the school's list of students.  Then save the changes to the DB again with the modifications.